# Datatables child.row using AJAX not refereshing

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, datatables

I'm trying to fetch child row data in Datatables using AJAX:

```
$('#myTable tbody').on('click', 'td', function () {
  var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
  var row = myTable.row( tr );   
    if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
      // This row is already open - close it
      row.child.remove();
      tr.removeClass('shown');
    } 
    else {
      $.post('/salesLines', 
        { token: localStorage.getItem('token'), 
           user: user.node, 
           id: localStorage.getItem('uniqueid')
      })
      .done(function(response) { 
        $.each(response.data, function (i, d) {  
        result += '<tr>'+'<td>'+d.qtysold+ '&nbsp;&nbsp;' + d.descr + '&nbsp;&nbsp;' + d.linetotal+'</td>'+'</tr>';
        row.child( $(result) ).show();  // use selector $() for result to align child rows with main table column headings
        tr.addClass('shown');
      });
    }
});
```

The AJAX request seem to cache the data even though it is using $.post.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: $.post is not cached.

`Pages fetched with POST are never cached, so the cache and ifModified options in jQuery.ajaxSetup() have no effect on these requests.`

From http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: Have you tried with simple ajax? $.ajax({
        url: "/myURL?",
        cache: false,
    });

Comment: Are you sure it's caching as opposed to "showing the same thing as before" - reason I ask is I dont see you actually updating the html anywhere other than make a string out of it (`result`).

Comment: @James, yes, wonder what  `result += '<tr>'+'<td>'+d.qtysold+ '&nbsp;&nbsp;' + d.descr + '&nbsp;&nbsp;' + d.linetotal+'</td>'+'</tr>';` is supposed to do...

Comment: Sorry guys, forgot the part where the result is appened to the DOM! Tried using a normal $.ajax request with cache: false and the result is the same. Should I just hide the rows using row.child.hide(); or row.child.remove() ?

Answer (score 0):

Changed the .on click event from

```
$('#myTable tbody').on('click', 'td', function () {
```

to:

```
$('#myTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
```

and now it works!